# what is lazy fetching in cocoa binding coredata?

Tags: ios, macos, core-data, cocoa-bindings

I watched a video tutorial on CoreData. I saw a that an option

- Uses Lazy fetching

To map an Object Model with Array Controller.

But did not understand what is Lazy fetching?

Answer (score 2):

That means that data would be actually fetched (automatically) not a the time of request, but at the time when controller would ask for data. For example consider large tableview with thousands of lines - they are not fetched all at the same time when request is executed, rather they are fetched by small parts dynamically when users scrolls tableview.

Comment: That means It loads data on demand, when user interact with it?

Comment: Yes, but I'd better say when controller "needs" data (because there can be different situation, not only UI)